# With Method that takes Func<T> on an Object Builder

Tags: c#, unit-testing, objectbuilder

I am trying to create an Object Builder so I can easily create objects for unit testing.  I would like to create a With() method so I can pass in a Func<> and it will set the correct property for me.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class EquipmentModelBuilder
{

    public EquipmentModel Object { get; set; }

    public EquipmentModelBuilder()
    {
        Object = new EquipmentModel();
    }

    public EquipmentModelBuilder WithCategory(int categoryId)
    {
        Object.EquipmentCategoryID = categoryId;
        return this;
    }

    public EquipmentModelBuilder With(Func<EquipmentModel> setter)
    {
        Object = setter.Invoke();
        return this;
    }

    public EquipmentModel Build()
    {
        return Object;
    }
}
```

Of course, the WithCategory() works, but I don't want to create all the methods for each property, I would like to be able to:

```
EquipmentModelBuilder.With(x => x.Property1 = 1).With(x => x.Property2 = "2").Build()
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an `Action<EquipmentModel>` as your argument rather than a `Func<EquipmentModel>`.

```
public EquipmentModelBuilder With(Action<EquipmentModel> setter)
{
    setter.Invoke(this.Object);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: +1 The call to `.Invoke` can be dropped, leaving a nicer `setter(this.Object)`.  Then rename `setter` to `initializeProperties(this.Object)` :-)

Comment: @Adam: Good point. I personally prefer to do it the way you describe, while some people like to use "Invoke." I think it makes them feel more object-oriented.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `Func<EquipmentModel>` is specifying a function that returns an EquipmentModel, so what you would want is an `Action<EquipmentModel>` which specifies a function with no return that accepts an EquipmentModel as parameter.